# How to register a function to be run when an update panel request is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Library: Bootstrap 3:Collapse.js.

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

});

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    //alert("this should work");
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse.in();
```

But it throws `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

The `alert` instead works no problem.

I thought JQuery was undefined but the page where this code is inherits all the appropriate scripts from a masterpage, so that's not the problem.

So, following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190549/how-can-i-run-some-javascript-after-an-update-panel-refreshes) I went on to trying

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(endRequestHandler);
```

But I made no progress.

I've also tried to [use the `body` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844061/running-javascript-after-update-panel-refresh), but still no joy.

Can please somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery does not have a collapse by it's self. What libraries are you using? Can we have some more context?

Comment: @Funonly sorry forgot, check update cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap and its libraries work mainly with classes and data-bindings.

There is no in() function for the collapse.js of bootstrap. If you want to reset the collapsable to be to collapse in you need to remove the class

```
$('#collapseTwo').removeClass('in');
```

This will make it reset.

If you would like the animation too you can trigger this with jquery by simulating a click (or how every your app triggers this collapse to show)

```
$(<selector for your button>).trigger('click')
```