# scriptmanager.registerstartupscript not working when PostBackTrigger fire inside updatepanel. why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I have a fileupdload control inside update panel. I have handle this upload by using following line 

`<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
 </Triggers>`

But when i using it i don't get the JavaScript message i.e. i have written like this 
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('File Upload Successfully!!')", true);`

Now My issue is this message not showing when i use this postbacktrigger. But when i remove the trigger tag, i got the message properly.

Please tell me what is the error.

Thanks for advance

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844061/running-javascript-after-update-panel-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a postbacktrigger for "btnSave", the page will do a full postback. Since the documentation for ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() says that it registers a script for every "asynchronous" postback, i guess it wont work.

Try using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock() instead